# How to consolidate script duplication?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I just want to know how you deal with long scripts and redundant information. Here is an example:

Suppose you have three tables: `table1`, `table2`, and `sometable`.

And you have

```
SELECT  
 id  = 1
 org = 'company'
 name = 'name'
 addr = 'arr'
 lang = 1      
cnt1 = if col1 = 1 then 1 else 1
 cnt2 = if col2 = 1 then 1 else 1
 cnt3 = if col2 = 1 then 1 else 1
INTO  table1
FROM   sometable



SELECT  
 id  = 2
 org = 'company2'
 name = 'name'
 addr = 'arr'
 lang = 1 
 cnt1 = if col1 = 1 then 1 else 1
 cnt2 = if col2 = 1 then 1 else 1
 cnt3 = if col2 = 1 then 1 else 1
INTO  table2
FROM   sometable
```

So the difference is that the starting stuff (not the `cnt*` fields) are changing. But as you can see there is a lot of overlap.

Also if I want to change the logic on the counts (which are common to both), then i have to go through both select statements and change them manually. this is error prone.

I was thinking something along this pseudocode:

```
   SELECT  
 id  = 1
 org = @variable
 name = @variable
 addr = 'arr'
 lang = 1 

  INCLUDE other columns/logic from somewhere else

INTO  table2
FROM   sometable
```

that way, if my logic changes for the `cnt` fields, I can just change it in one spot and it would change everywhere.

I am open to any suggestions. SMSS addin, stored procs, or some other ugly or beautiful method people know.

Answer (score 1):

If you have something THAT similar and you need to call it more than once or twice, I would put it into another stored proc that you can call:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertStuff (@id int, @org varchar(100), @name varchar(100), @lang int)
AS

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT id = ' + @id + ' ' +
           'org = ''' + @org + ''' ' +
           'name = ''' + @name + ''' ' +
           'lang = ''' + @lang + ''' ' +
           'cnt 1 = CASE WHEN Col1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2'
           -- All your other common stuff here

EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks I was thinking that. But I forgot to add that there might be group by or other where clause conditions and obviously you cant say `group by @var`

Comment: You can in this example since we are using dynamic SQL.

Comment: for the other groups, maybe you can throw some CASE statements there.

Comment: EXEC? For shame! :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I thought about it before posting but decided this was just an example and not production code :)